# Catch invalid parameter in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If we have a controller action like this

```
@GetMapping("/oauth2/token")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> isTokenValid(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
//... code
}
```

Then how can I handle the exception that happens when a user submits no token.

---

And when I have the following Controller action

```
@PostMapping("/account/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateAccount(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody AccountDTO dto) {
```

how can I handle the there the exception when the DTO can not be parsed and does Jackson validate the data when trying to make the DTO out of it?

Comment: Check this: https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Comment: you should use some annotations from: validation-api